# Is there a way of skipping the recomended missions on mobile strike?

Tags: mobile-strike

On Mobile Strike, there are 4 times of missions: Alliance, Daily, VIP and recommended. The recommended mission appears at the bottom of the screen[image]

Is there a way of changing this, because I do not want to complete this mission. I am able to complete other missions that come up on the recommended mission list, however, I only appear to get VIP points when I complete the one that is listed. I do not have space for 10 banks so is there a way of passing this mission?

[Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how+to+skip+missions+on+mobile+strike&ie=&oe=) appears useless in this situation.